# Can you make hexagon in perspective using shapes in photoshop? (see image)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

Outline hexagon with rounded corners. Is this possible in photoshop?

[image]

Comment: Hi Marko, could you please explain what you mean? I don't understand your question. Thanks!

Comment: How do you make the outline shape? (arrow pointed)

Comment: Just draw it with the Pen Tool and add a stroke.

Comment: @BillyKerr Ok, tough there was an simpler way. Tell me have you ever had problem with Polygon tool (mine wont let me pass 4x4 px when I drag the mouse)?

Comment: If you have another question, about a tool, for example, it might be a better idea to ask a new question, provided it's on-topic (and I'm sorry, I don't think 'my polygon tool won't let me pass 4x4 px is going to be on-topic here). Please have a look at both the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to get an understanding of how Stack Exchange works and what is on and off topic on this stack. tl;dr: we are a Q&A site, and not a forum. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Vincent Ok, you can close this question. Thanks you

Comment: This would be much easier to do in Illustrator

Comment: Yup, I vote for illustrator too, or even Inkscape which is free. Photoshop's not really the right kind of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way in photoshop, yet. Use illustrator instead.

> Just draw it with the Pen Tool and add a stroke. – @Billy Kerr
>
> This would be much easier to do in Illustrator – @Vinny

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept it as bitmap, you get it easily. Only start at high enough pixel dimensions to get a sharp looking result.

Let's assume you need the wanted shape in size 1000 x 1000 pixels with six pixels wide grey stroke. Start by making an image of just that size. Fill the background with a good solid work color, for example black or blue which is easy to see on Photoshop's emty background checkerboard. Then

- transform the background to a layer by doubleclicking it in the layers panel
- select all
- goto Edit > Transform > Scale and type the scaling percentage both horizontally and vertically =50%
- duplicate the layer, move squares in both layers to the opposite corners of the image. Check at high zoom that the corners of the squares meet at the center without a gap.

You should have now:

[image]

Take the polygonal lasso tool, add a selection and paint onto the image to make a slanted hexagon. It's good to have a new layer and when you are happy of the supplement, merge all layers.Here the supplement is shown temporarily in different color and partially transparent:

[image]

Check in high zoom that the corners fit before merging the layers! The supplement can be redrawn or edited if needed (=Edit > Transform > Distort)

- Increase the canvas size so that the rest of your arwork will fit. Now you have:

[image]

The corners must be rounded. Photoshop unfortunetely hasn't good and easy control to make the corners roundings different, if wanted. Different roundings need selections with paths or circles.  Easily the corners will get only the same rounding. I assume it to be ok. So

- select with the magic wand the transparent area
- goto Refine Edge, set full moothing, no feathering, 100% contrast, OK
- press DEL

Repeat the refinement + DEL a couple of times to get enough rounding. Now you have:

[image]

There's still the selection active.

Invert the selection (=select the hexagon). Contract the selection 6 pixels.Press DEL. Now you have:

[image]

Next step is to desaturate, adjust the brightness and possibly recolor. A Hue/Saturation adjustment layer switched to affect to only one layer is good. The black background is added to see the grey result properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved by putting two stroke effects on the layer. The top stroke would need to be black. The bottom stroke would need to be white or grey and slightly larger than the black stroke.